# Help with filtered views across multiple pages! SHAREPOINT 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, shared-libraries

I'm rather new to this SharePoint stuff so be easy with me :)

What I am trying to do is have one complete list with all documents (Shared Documents), each assigned a certain DocumentType (managed metadata), and then show only some of these files depending on each web page within sharepoint you look at. Now i know about key filters, but don't I have to set these each time i want to filter? I basically want a filtered view on metadata for each page all related to Shared Documents

Thanks in advance

:)

Answer (score 0):

Navigate the site containing list or library.
Press "SiteAction"->"View all site content" and choose your list or library.
In the ribbon choose "List"->"Create View"-> "Custom view in SP Designer".Create your personal view.
After it, you can go to "List"-> Current view" and choose your view.